# Serving html files has no extension

Tags: .htaccess, litespeed

I have html files and has no html extension, when I link to this files apache downloads file instead open it.

How can I serve this html files? (with htaccess)

Note: I need this to serve more than 10k html files not for single special file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess setting the mimetype for a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628826/htaccess-setting-the-mimetype-for-a-single-file)

Comment: I have 10K files not single file

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation for the [`<Files>` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files) you can use wildcard strings with ? and *, and nest the Files directives inside Directory directives, to target any number of files without explicitly defining their names.  Within the directive, use `AddType` or `ForceType` as you need.  If you want to target all files, for example, and serve them all with the same mime type (in this example, HTML), then you might use:

```
<Files "*">
    ForceType text/html *
</Files>
```

Comment: Try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398123/apache-2-4-set-mime-type-of-file-without-extension), (using ForceType instead of AddType)? I'll update my answer here if that works for you.

Comment: I tried `<FilesMatch "^[^.]+$">
    ForceType text/plain
    </FilesMatch>` but not working

Comment: If you just copied and pasted the code, then no - you're looking for {text/html} not {text/plain} right?  So you'll have to edit it a bit.

Comment: I edited for my case as text/html, I already tried this before posting question

Comment: How are you determining whether it's working or not?  Are you inspecting the response in detail using a browser's dev tools (or a tool like wget or curl) to confirm that Apache is not setting the `Content-Type` header in the response?  What `Content-Type` header is it sending instead, if any?

Comment: I just visiting link and its downloading http://bilgisayarcenneti.com/urun/documate-3640-a4-flatbed-duplex-40-ppm-80ipm-100sf-adf-99-one-touch

Comment: returned response from server `Accept-Ranges: bytes

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 65519

Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Date: Wed, 09 May 2018 16:59:05 GMT

Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 15:31:26 GMT

Server: LiteSpeed`

Comment: I'm not familiar with LiteSpeed, but it sounds like the .htaccess syntax should be the same.  Your .htaccess file is in the /urun directory?  If so, as a test, can you move the `ForceType text/html` outside of the `<Files>` block to see if that even works?  If it works it will affect all of the files in the directory, so that won't be a good solution if you have other file types in there, but it should help you determine whether the server supports the ForceType directive properly.

Comment: I used like this and added htaccess to root and urun directory ` ForceType text/html
 AddType text/html *`  and return same response `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

Comment: Have you been able to use .htaccess files successfully on this server before, for any other purpose (redirects, etc)?

Comment: Yes i use another directives it work without problem